# ASP.NET MVC intranet application based on a workgroup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workgroup

Is `ASP.NET MVC` intranet application intented only to be used as a `Windows-domain based` application or there's a possiblity to run it inside a `workgroup`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The word [`Intranet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) has no correlation with any network operating system (Windows Domain, Workgroup, etc).  How you build your web based application (using any language) is indifferent to who can access it.  So to answer your direct question, you can use ASP.Net MVC to build a website that can be accessed by anyone on a local network if you configure the website and/or hosting environment (IIS) in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

MVC (Model View Controler) is a way to develop application (web + desktop) and can be used as Windows-domain App or inside a workgorup or without of both